# Setup the functions getDataSet and tearDown

Tags: php, database, unit-testing, dataset, teardown

Im trying to set up a test for my code.. And i haven't rly found any good information about getDataSet.

What does getDataSet do? Why do i need it? And how should the function look like?

And the function tearDown.. ive been looking at it, and ive only seen that it deletes data from a table.. Can you configure it to delete the EXACT data that you just inserted right now? In my setUp i insert data in my database and after each test i would like to delete the data that was inserted.

Comment: It's better to have a separate test base and truncate it (and seed) before running tests. Each test must be independent of the others and initial data.

Comment: Hmm.. I see.. But i dont want to delete all rows/data in the table. I just wanna delete the data that was created in setUp...

In setUp i make Insert and put something in the DB. And then in the tearDown i only wanna delete the data that i just inserted.. Becaouse i got other data in the table that i wanna keep.